# Can I get one table to display differently to others on a responsive view?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I'm building a website in wordpress, using the 'Rookie' theme, and have installed the sportpress plugin, as well as an accordion plugin.

I'd like to display a table in accordions, but also make it display properly when on a mobile device. This is the webpage  >   http://wnu.054.myftpupload.com/fixtures-and-results/

I've sorted this for the majority of tables (fixtures for the month) using the following CSS:

```css
.table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
    
    thead th {
        display: none;
    }

    td, th {
        display: block;
    }

    td[data-th]:before  {
        content: attr(data-th);
    }
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    }

    td,
    th {
    padding: 0.5em;
    }

    th {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    }

    thead th {
    background-color: #999;
    color: white;
    }

    td &gt; div {
    float: right;
    }
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
thead th {
    display: none;
}

thead th:first-child:after {
    content: "'s";
}

td, th {
    display: block;
    width: 100% !important;
}


td[data-th]:before {
    content: attr(data-th);
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    min-width: 10rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem I've got is that I don't have access to edit the tables in Sportspress so I can't edit the table data on the Player stats table so that it includes the 'data-th="heading"' - meaning the headers don't display.

Without the CSS above, the sportspress table displays OK (not perfect, but not bad either), I was wondering if I can set it so that the sportspress table ignores the CSS I've set up (on the responsive view) or if there is a better way to do this? If possible, the sportpress table would display the headers, but I think I'd have to upgrade from the free version?

Comment: `table:not(.sportspress) ...` e.g. `table:not(.sportspress) td` etc.

Comment: Sorry for the daft question - would that have to go on each table setting?

Comment: Yes. That's why people are using a css preprocess (scss, less etc.) to avoid repeating selectors.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've tried adding that and I'm still struggling, the changes I make seem to bodge up the original tables. I don't suppose you could provide a bit more of an example could you?

Comment: If you'd create an example using codesanbox or codepen or something with the most updated code, I'll try to figure it out share the results with you.

Comment: I'll have a go at doing this - thanks for your help